# iOS - Scrolling collectionview to top issue

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with section header named "XXX".

I have this function implemented:

```
 self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Yes, indeed, the collection view moves to top but it doesn't shows 'XXX' my section header.

How can I scroll collection view all the way to top ??

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.collectionView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: I have to double tap at the uitabbar button to scroll all the way to the top ??